# How to access data directory when updating an Android app where I have changed the package in the Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have an Android app in the Market and I want to push an update. The problem is that after refactoring my base package name in the Manifest file is completely different. I feel I'm in trouble because (in order to migrate old data) I need to access a file stored in:

/data/data/old_app_pkg_name/app_data

but with my refactoring I'll probably be able to access the data directory in:

/data/data/new_app_pkg_name/app_data

Am I stuck with using the same old package name if I want to access the data directory of the original app? Or I do have access to that directory when pushing an update even if I change the package in the Manifest?

Best!

German

Comment: Beyond this problem, your app will be a fundamentally different app on the Market. The package *has to stay the same* and be signed by the same signing key in order to be considered an update by the Market. Leave the package in the `<manifest>` element alone, even if this means you need to fully-qualify the class names for `<activity>` and such, and that you need to manually add `import` statements to pick up the `R` class that will be generated in the old package. IOW, refactoring is fine, but changing the package in the manifest is not.

Comment: Ok I have now changed my package name back to the original one but what happens if my main activity (launcher) fully qualified name has changed? Could this affect the location of the data directory in any way?

Comment: AFAIK, the directory is driven solely by the manifest package. The fully-qualified class name of the `LAUNCHER` activity should not matter.

Comment: Just for the record this info was right, main activity can be renamed it's all about the manifest package. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't. Unfortunately Android generates a new user the combination of package name and signing certificate. If you had created your old files as WORLD_READABLE on the SD card then maybe you would have been able to do it, but as far as I am aware once you change the package name you can't get to the old directory any more.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question and just for the benefit of anyone struggling with this here's a great new blog post from the Android team about what to keep when updating your app:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

(I wish it was available when I asked this question but it wasn't, it's new)

Best!

German